# Flying saucer/OpenPdf same string html content but different byte[]

Tags: java, thymeleaf, integration-testing, flying-saucer, openpdf

I'm using flying saucer pd with openpdf to gnerate pdf.
I generate the pdf from an htm file using thymleaf 3.

All works fine, but not the test.

My idea was to create a testing method that generate a pdf file ... after that i convert the ButeArrayStream to a byte[] ... and finally test the byte[] generated with the byte[] i got from a previous compilation.

But, i found out that ItextRenderer.createPdf(htmlContent) generate different byte[] each time.

Is it normal ? is there a way to get the same byte[] each time ?

Comment: Notice: the html content it's the same each time ... so is not thymleaf who generate different html ... it's really the createPdf method of ItextRenderer.

Comment: It is probably normal, I would expect it to contain meta-data such as a rendering timestamp. Can you inspect the PDF to see where the differences are?

Comment: For the purpose of testing, if you want to test your own code and not Flying Saucer, it should be enough to test the HTML input to the PDF renderer.

Comment: Compare the bytes, maybe visual as hexadecimal. Maybe the changes are small. For instance at the start a couple of byte are unspecified, which is normally filled with non-ASCII so Unix recognize the data as binary. However if the length varies also, internal numbers which are internal addresses will be shifted too.

Comment: Alternatively one might render both pdfs to images apply some smart image operation, and inspect the differences.

Comment: i'm convinced with just testing html content ... it:s enought i think

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. If you want to test your document, you need to do a structural or visual comparison, not a byte comparison. To have an idea on how to do that, have a look at the [`CompareTool`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.9/com/itextpdf/kernel/utils/CompareTool.html) class of iText 7 (OpenPdf is a fork of an older version of iText, so the API may seem familiar).

Comment: `Set` is not randomizing things, though. Running the same code, on the same JVM and architecture, with the same inputs will produce the same output.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen differences between Java 7 on Windows and Java 11 on Linux.